# Ayuda con una consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, web

Hola buenas tengo un problema y es que llevo varios días sin poder solucionar esto. He estado investigando, pero no he logrado buscar algo que lo solucione, o a veces no lo entiendo.

Tengo una tabla llamada exámenes en la cual debo consultar el historial del estudiante

CONCEPTO  ETAPA FECHA           RESULTADO

10________1805A__09/Abr/2018_____8

11________1803B__05/Mar/2018_____5

12________1803B__05/Mar/2018_____5

12________1805B__30/Abr/2018_____7

13________1802B__06/Feb/2018_____5

Este es el resultado que me entrega, como podemos ver, el concepto 12 esta dos veces y es que el alumno presentó una vez y lo reprobó, y a la segunda lo logró pasar con 7.

Cuando lo agrupo por el concepto, me aparece el concepto 12 en el cual el estudiante reprobó y no en la que ha pasado.

¿Como puedo hacer para que me aparezca el concepto 12  más reciente?

Perdón si lo toman como una pregunta  muy sencilla apenas ando creciendo mi experiencia en MYSQL y no habia llegado a un tipo de problema asi.

Mi consulta es esta.

```
SELECT CONCEPTO,ETAPA,FECHA,RESULTADO FROM `examenes` WHERE CRED=648 ORDER BY CONCEPTO;
```

Comment: Hola! ¿Podrías poner la sentencia MYSQL del query que estas utilizando? Ayudaría para ver como lo estas mapeando ya que puede haber muchas formas de hacerlo

Comment: Si claro este es "SELECT CONCEPTO,ETAPA,FECHA,RESULTADO FROM `examenes` WHERE CRED=648 ORDER BY CONCEPTO;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el HAVING para decirle que obtenga la fecha mas alta

```
SELECT *
FROM Alumnos
GROUP BY id_Alumno
HAVING FECHA = max(FECHA)
```

o puedes hacer una subconsulta

```
SELECT *
FROM Alumnos a
WHERE FECHA = (
               SELECT MAX(FECHA)
               FROM Alumnos a1
               WHERE a.id_alumno = a1.id_alumno
              )
```

Comment: Lo estoy aplicando de esta maneera pero me sigue apareciendo el resultado reprobado y no el que ya paso asi quedo SELECT CONCEPTO,ETAPA,FECHA,RESULTADO FROM examenes e WHERE FECHA = (SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM examenes e1 WHERE e.FOLIO=e1.FOLIO AND e.CONCEPTO=e1.CONCEPTO) AND CRED=648 ORDER BY CONCEPTO;

Comment: El campo Folio también se repite como el Concepto?

Comment: no, el folio siempre es diferente

Comment: Intenta quitando del where el Folio, para que solo filtre por los que estan repetidos solo deja SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM examenes e1 WHERE e.CONCEPTO=e1.CONCEPTO

Comment: listo quedo, otra pregunta y si algunos tienen vacio la fecha como hago que aun asi me aparesta se puede con el IS_NULL???

Comment: En MYSQL es IFNULL, SELECT IFNULL(Campo, "Valor por Default");, no olvides votar positivo en la respuesta :) espero haberte ayudado

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS.